# CasperJS with JSON.parse

Tags: casperjs

When I run the following code, I get the following:

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.emit('error', error)')**

I asked this earlier, but im rephrasing.  It appears that the JSON object is undefined in the casper function.

If I do JSON.parse() outside, then its not undefined.

Thoughts on how to get this working?

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
});

var site = 'http://my.internalsite.com';

casper.start(site);

casper.run(function() {
    var currentURL = this.getCurrentUrl();
    this.echo('URL: ' + currentURL);
    var json_string = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());
    this.echo(json_string);
    this.exit();            
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could possibly be due to `this.exit()` getting called before `JSON.parse(this.getPageContent())`

You could try the following:

```js
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
});

var site = 'http://xkcd.com/info.0.json';

casper.start(site);

casper.then(function() {
    var currentURL = this.getCurrentUrl();
    this.echo('URL: ' + currentURL);
    var json_string = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());
    require('utils').dump(json_string);
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: that worked for me.   i guess im not fully understanding how casperjs works.  why was the this.exit being called before JSON.parse()?

Comment: `Casper.getPageContent()` makes an asynchronous call to `Casper.evaluate()`, which will cause `Casper.exit()` to run before the value gets returned from `getPageContent()`